# Switching disks

Tags: centos, hard-disk, dd

We currently have two servers with SATA disks. The box load on the box every so often jumps. We see a direct correlation between the IO wait and the system usage going up. When ever the IO is high the system CPU usage jumps as well. The server has hardware raid with the drive showing as /dev/sda. We re running CentOS. We want to install two SSD's in a raid 1 as well, boot from a USB key and then use dd to copy from the SATA disks over to the SSD's. Once we copy everything over we will remove the original array and leave just the second. Will this work? How does Linux assign which disk is /dev/sda or /dev/sdb?

Comment: As far as i know which device is assigned sda sdb sdX is not deterministic, and that's why many of us utilize UUIDs (yet there are other options).  there are many good internet sources for persistent device naming, here is just one (and a good one): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming

Comment: What type of partitions do you have on top of that RAID massive?

Comment: Can't seem to figure out how to do newline here. Here is the output of the sever

http://pastebin.ca/3718909

Comment: @DovidBender regarding formatting, you can't put newlines in a comment, but you can do much of the rest of the markdown which you can read up on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: It's typically better to edit the question to  include new details arrising from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the `LVM` partition I would recommend you the following steps:

First switch the `fstab` and `grub` configuration to use `UUID`s for /boot volume the system uses.

Next, attach the `SSD` device, boot the system from the `RAID` and partition the `SSD` to have two partitions: for a new /boot volume and a new `LVM` `PV`.

Then add that new `PV` to existing `VG` and migrate all `LV`s to an `SSD`'s `PV` (check with `man lvm` for all necessary commands).

After migration is done, remove the `RAID`'s `PV` from a `Volume Group`

Then copy with tar or rsync the content of /boot file system to the new location (the /boot partition on `SSD`) preserving `ACL`s and `SE` contexts, adjust the kernel settings in the grub configuration and install grub on `SSD`.